# Image Processing remove noise

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have the follwing image where i have to clean the picture as much as i can.
Removing the small dots around the names.
I made the following processing but without big results

```
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray_image, 3)
ret3, th3 = cv2.threshold(blur, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV  + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(th3, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
skimage.io.imsave('../output/processing/' + os.path.basename(image),thresh)
```

[image]
what can i do ?

Comment: You can start by sharing the original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using simple thresholding, you can use [adaptive Gaussian thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) which is robust against noise and may give better results than Otsu's binarization, assuming your noise is the same intensity as your desired text.